# Changing list items in javascript

Tags: javascript, html-lists

I am trying to change the list items in an entire document. I'm using the following code, but I get an error. What am I doing wrong?

```
function changeListItems() {
var listItem = document.getElementsByTagName("ul");
var docItem = listItem.getElementsByTagName("li");
docItem.setAttribute("class", "list-group-item");
};
changeListItems();
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hQJeE/)

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: What is your error, where in the page are you putting your javascript?  etc. We need more info.

Answer (score 5):

Because [`document.getElementsByTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByTagName) Returns an HTMLCollection of elements with the given tag name.

you should loop through each element and add class to it.

For Ex:

```
var docItem = listItem.getElementsByTagName("li");

for(var i=0; i< docItem.length; i++)
{
  docItem[i].className = "list-group-item"
}
```

- [`className`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.className)

Comment: You're adding the class to any ordered list element that might be on the page, too. The OP clearly doesn't want that. Nested loops can be avoided using `querySelectorAll`, which is supported nativily by all browsers, even IE8 and up

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem Yup You're right! Nesting loops must be avoided as it'll become too complex and messy.

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem—perhaps you can start a movement to add iterators to DOM APIs. Consider `document.querySelectorAll('ul li').each(function(el){el.className = 'foo'})`.

Comment: @RobG That is also a good way to accomplish the same :) Nice work!

Comment: @RobG: No need: `Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('ul li'), function(node) { node.setAttribute('class', 'foo'); });` works just fine :). Added that to my answer, too

Comment: In querySelectorAll, am I still referencing just the li tag in the list?

Comment: And I guess I'm still unsure when a loop is need or when it will just run over the whole DOM.

Answer (score 2):

`getElementsByTagName` return a `NodeList`, you have to iterate over it.

Since you have two levels of tags, you'd have to write nested loops. But it's simpler to get all the list items at once with `querySelectorAll`.

```
function changeListItems() {
    var docItem = document.querySelectorAll("ul li");
    for (var i = 0; i < docItem.length; i++) {
        docItem[i].setAttribute("class", "list-group-item");
    }
}
```